# Monterey Calendar

Tags: sleep-wake, calendar

If a repeat question, please forgive me.  With age, I am losing the memory to check my calendar every day and therefore just forget some issues.  I have searched all the major search engines with the following question and find nothing.  **When I reopen the desktop from sleep mode, is there a way to force the calendar to open with it so I can check and recheck what is going on in my life?**  It seemed to be a simple idea, and notifications are on, but there seems to be no means of activating the calendar to open from sleep.  The computer is never turned off so that is not an issue.  I just want the calendar to appear whenever it awakes from sleep no matter how many times in a day.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Personally, I never quit Calendar - however, it is still capable of sending notifications whether it's running or not. Do you have notifications set?

Comment: I guess that is the trick.  I have a habit of closing everything when I am done with it.  Yes, the notifications are on, but a visual pop-up is what I had wanted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small script that 1) invokes sleep, and then 2) opens Calendar.

But this would only happen if you ran the script manually, not if the machine spontaneously decided to sleep.

Comment: Thank you, but I personally have no idea how to write a script.   I had thought about that also, but had initially hoped there was a small app that would accomplish this on my M1 desktop.

Comment: I might be willing to attempt such a script for you, but you would have to invoke it yourself — it would not work if your computer is set to go to sleep after a certain idle time. So, you would have to disable letting the computer go to sleep by itself, and then remember to run this script (a simple double-click on a file) when you wanted to sleep the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something else to try to help you to remember to use Calendar.

I have installed [Mini Calendar](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mini-calendar/id1088779979?mt=12). This is on the menu bar, and so it is simple to access. It looks like a tiny calendar, and when you click on it, it shows you the current month.

[image: Mini Calendar]

That does not show you your appointments, but if you then double-click on any date there, it will open the "real" Calendar for you, where all your appointments and such are stored!

It has a preference you can set to always display a translucent mini-calendar on top of everything, but I find that annoying. I don't think it would help you, because it is not clickable to bring up the Calendar app.

Mini Calendar is free. Clicking the link above should take you to the App Store, where you can download and install it.

If this doesn't suit you, I found [a list of other menu-bar calendar applications](https://techwiser.com/best-calendar-apps-for-mac-that-you-can-access-from-menu-bar/). Something in that list might suit you better.

In particular, there's [one on that list that will show your next appointment](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/next-meeting/id1017470484?mt=12) right on the menu bar! It is also free.

[image: Next Meeting menu-bar app]

Having a menu-bar calendar might not be what you wanted, but it might be enough to remind you to do a couple clicks to open your Calendar!

Answer (score 0):

My life revolves around my calendar as well.

If you are running macOS Sonoma, set up a widget on your desktop for your calendar.

It's always there on the desktop, the app does not need to be left running.